Firebase Log Event not showing up in console
I am trying to create a custom firebase log event to check how many players completed a single level in a unity game, but the event I created is not showing up in the console.
Here is the log event code -
FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("Level "+SaveController.LevelId, 
                           new Parameter("Level Id : ",SaveController.LevelId));

I tried the implementation as per the instructions from the official website of firebase for unity integration and even the firebase is initializing every time and no error or warning shows up when I run the game.


Parameter name can't have space in it. Basically rename the
parameter name from Level Id to level_id

Also I would encourage you to use recommended events for Games: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9267735?hl=en there are
plenty of events and parameters that can be used and GA4 interface
will be more friendly upon your event collection


